Create a PR and Auto merge before Test deployment with GitHub Actions
We are using dev branch for dev env and main branch for test env. I need to create a auto merge PR from dev to main branch via GitHub actions once the dev environment deployment is completed. So created a job with the below script to use GitHub CLI.
I have created a token in GitHub and I am Enterprise User.
I referred the page [1]:Create pull request with github action
automatedprfortestdeployment:
 name: Automated PR for Test deployment
 runs-on: windows-latest
 needs: [devdeployjob]
 environment: test
 env:
  GH_TOKEN: ${{ github.token }}  
 permissions:
  pull-requests: write
 steps:
  - name: 'Create PR'
    shell: pwsh
    run: |
     git --version
     go install golang.org/dl/go1.10.7@latest
     go version
     git clone https://github.com/cli/cli.git gh-cli
     cd gh-cli
     go run script\\build.go
     gh version
     echo "Creating Automated PR to merge from dev into main"
     gh pr create -B origin/main -H origin/dev --title 'Merge dev into 
     main' --body 'Created by Github action'

Receiving the below error.
Creating Automated PR to merge from dev into main pull request create failed: GraphQL: Unauthorized: As an Enterprise Managed User, you cannot access this content (createPullRequest) Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

you could create a personal access token to authorize with

@DanielA.White I am using the PAT for auth.You can see the env variables mentioned in code. that is when i got this error. I have Repo admin access and I am an Org member. Will this permission not suffice for auto PR creation. Please advice.

That’s for the action runner.
